# Cannot get my css media queries to work with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am using bootstrap v3.3.6 and for the life of me, I cannot see how to override the default media queries. I have tried various ways to overcome this, but nothing I try works. The query does not even appear in firebug or chrome developer.

From what I can see, bootstrap layout there media queries like thus:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  /* code goes here */
  }
```

But from all research I have done trying to overcome this, media queries are laid out as:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* code goes here */
}
```

Should both queries work?

I have posted the code I am using and be very grateful if someone could help me overcome this. Many thanks

@media (min-width: 320px) {

```
.navbar-brand {
    /*float: left;*/
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    /*line-height: 20px;*/
    }
}
```

Comment: try to add `!important` to your css

Comment: I did and I removed them prior to posting. Thanks

Comment: Suggesting the use of `!important` may not be the brightest idea.

Answer (score 1):

So there are 2things which could be the reason for the problem:

First: bootstrap uses more precise selector than you do. E.g.

```
.div .navbar-brand { code goes here;}
```

Or if you use the same selector bootstrap gets loaded after your CSS and overwrites yours.

So make sure you get loaded later, you have same or more precise selectors and you should be fine.

If you can´t fix it either way you can use !important, but thats rather bad practice

Comment: Yeh I tried that but didn't make any difference. How do I make sure I am loading my css later? Thanks

Comment: assuming you have a html file with a <script>-tag loading your css and bootstrap css, just make sure that the script-tag with your css comes after bootstrap.

For further questions I would need to know more about your code

Comment: I am using wordpress and loading the css through the index file. I am not using a seperate css file but a css custom plugin. Would tht cause a problem?

Comment: Well I always made seperate css files, so I can´t answer if  the css custom plugin is the problem.
Normally you enqueue the css in the functions.php and should be able to load your styles after bootstrap this way. Sorry for not being able to help you further here!

Comment: Thanks Marcel. One last question. What exactly does this statement mean. @media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1080px;
  }
} also in the inspector it refers to grid.less:30 and not the custom css sheet i have now done.

Comment: @media (min-width: 1200px) means "use the following css styles if your screen-width is more then 1200px" --> google "media queries"